# Python Pandas Flatten nested JSON

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas

I'm new to python & pandas and it took me awhile to get the results I wanted using below. Basically, I am trying to flatten a nested JSON. While json_normalize works, there are columns where it contains a list of objects(key/value). I want to breakdown that list and add them as separate columns. Below sample code I wrote worked out fine but was wondering if this could be simplified or improved further or an alternative? Most of the articles I've found relies on actually naming the columns and such (codes that I cant pick up on just yet), but I would rather have this as a function and name the columns dynamically. The output csv will be used for Power BI.

```
with open('json.json', 'r') as json_file: jsondata = json.load(json_file)

df = pd.json_normalize(jsondata['results'], errors='ignore')

y = df.columns[df.applymap(type).eq(list).any()]

for x in y:

    df = df.explode(x).reset_index(drop=True)

    df_exploded = pd.json_normalize(df.pop(x))

    for i in df_exploded.columns:
        
        df_exploded = df_exploded.rename(columns={i:x + '_' + i})

    df = df.join(df_exploded)

df.to_csv('json.csv')
```

Sample JSON Format (Not including the large JSON I was working on):

```
data = {
        'results': [
                        {
                            'recordType': 'recordType',
                            'id': 'id',
                            'values': 
                              {
                                'orderType': [{'value': 'value', 'text': 'text'}],
                                'type': [{'value': 'value', 'text': 'text'}],
                                'entity': [{'value': 'value', 'text': 'text'}],
                                'trandate': 'trandate'
                              }
                        }
                   ]
       }
```

The values part when json_normalized, doesn't get flatten and required explode and joined.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(jsondata['results'],meta=['recordType','id'])[['recordType','id','values.trandate']]

record_paths = [['values','orderType'],['values','type'],['values','entity']]
for i in record_paths:
    df = pd.concat([df,pd.json_normalize(jsondata['results'],record_path=i,record_prefix=i[1])],axis=1)

df.to_csv('json.csv')
```

Or (**much faster**):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'recordType':[i['recordType'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'id':[i['id'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'values.trandate':[i['values']['trandate'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'orderTypevalue':[i['values']['orderType'][0]['value'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'orderTypetext':[i['values']['orderType'][0]['text'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'typevalue':[i['values']['type'][0]['value'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'typetext':[i['values']['type'][0]['text'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'entityvalue':[i['values']['entity'][0]['value'] for i in jsondata['results']],
                 'entitytext':[i['values']['entity'][0]['text'] for i in jsondata['results']]})

df.to_csv('json.csv')
```

**Output**:

```
|    | recordType   | id   | values.trandate   | orderTypevalue   | orderTypetext   | typevalue   | typetext   | entityvalue   | entitytext   |
|---:|:-------------|:-----|:------------------|:-----------------|:----------------|:------------|:-----------|:--------------|:-------------|
|  0 | recordType   | id   | trandate          | value            | text            | value       | text       | value         | text         |
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is what I was trying to avoid because I will be pulling multiple different reports with different columns, wouldnt that mean I would need to write multiple of these with different paths and meta? The initial code I had basically gets repurposed as it only looks for columns that are lists values, explodes them, then concat?

Comment: Sorry i didn't read the last part of the question.. Your solution is good and seems working for now. However, I can't be sure that this will always work correctly. Will json formats always be the same? What if there are unwanted fields in the json data ? If you do not have a large number of reports, I prefer to use a separate function for each format/report.

Comment: NetSuite Saved Search called via API seems to return consistent JSON formatting like my sample. Problem is how they handle certain criteria, they include Internal ID and it’s Text Value, so I will modify that code to drop the value part and keep the text part. The reports will be large as multiple departments for the company I work for will have their own requirements. I guess we’ll revisit the problems when they arise. Thanks for your help :)